# Cannot push a file to virtual android device for testing

Tags: android

I am trying to push an mp3 file using the DDMS to the android device but I get the following error

```
[2013-02-20 00:09:04 - ddms] transfer error: Read-only file system
[2013-02-20 00:09:04] Failed to push selection: Read-only file system
```

how can I push the file to the device so that it is available for my code ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: you need to change permission and please tell which OS you are using

Comment: You can put your mp3 file in asset folder of your project and you can access that file

Comment: Could you tell me how I could check which android operating system I am using ?

Comment: actually i meant r u using Linux or Windows

Comment: Windows - Developing on Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to push to a location on the device that is not writable for adb. Try to push to another location, for example on the SD card.

Comment: The SD card doesnt appear as a folder in my DDMS. It appears as a file and when attempting to push to it - I get the message `[2013-02-20 00:20:46] Failed to push the item(s).
[2013-02-20 00:20:46] null`

Comment: DDMS does not follow links, you have to find out where the filesystem is mounted on your device (this may differ depending on device and Android version). For example on my Nexus S the SD card is at `/storage/sdcard0/`.